# Entities not persisting in integration tests (Hibernate + Spring Roo ActiveRecord )

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, junit4, spring-roo

After much hassle I'm here for help. I am not able to persist data to development database (and also Embedded database) from a test case. When I run the test case without asserting it passes without any exception. I using Spring Roo generated entities. With the same application context configuration I'm able to save data to the database from Spring controller. So I'm convinced that I don't have any problem with my entities.

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" })
@Transactional
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Rollback(false)
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setRolename("ROLE_ADMIN");
        // No Exception here on trying to persist
        role.persist();
        // Getting Exception here.. "No transaction is in progress"
        // role.flush();

        // Getting "No entity found for query exception"
        assertEquals(Role.findRolesByRolenameEquals("ROLE_ADMIN").getSingleResult().getRolename(), "ROLE_ADMIN");
    }
}
```

My applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd      
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        ">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />

    <context:spring-configured />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*"
            type="regex" />
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${testDatabase.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${testDatabase.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${testDatabase.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${testDatabase.password}" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager"  proxy-target-class="true" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitTest" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitTest"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.company.domain.User</class>
        <class>com.company.domain.Role</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

EDIT: Added Persistence logic
My Persistence logic in Role_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj

```
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. THIS FILE IS MANAGED BY SPRING ROO.
// You may push code into the target .java compilation unit if you wish to edit any member(s).

package com.company.domain;

import com.company.domain.Role;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

privileged aspect Role_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord {

    @PersistenceContext
    transient EntityManager Role.entityManager;

    public static final EntityManager Role.entityManager() {
        EntityManager em = new Role().entityManager;
        if (em == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)");
        return em;
    }

    public static long Role.countRoles() {
        return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT COUNT(o) FROM Role o", Long.class).getSingleResult();
    }

    public static List<Role> Role.findAllRoles() {
        return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Role o", Role.class).getResultList();
    }

    public static Role Role.findRole(Integer roleId) {
        if (roleId == null) return null;
        return entityManager().find(Role.class, roleId);
    }

    public static List<Role> Role.findRoleEntries(int firstResult, int maxResults) {
        return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Role o", Role.class).setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(maxResults).getResultList();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void Role.persist() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        this.entityManager.persist(this);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void Role.remove() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        if (this.entityManager.contains(this)) {
            this.entityManager.remove(this);
        } else {
            Role attached = Role.findRole(this.roleId);
            this.entityManager.remove(attached);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void Role.flush() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        this.entityManager.flush();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void Role.clear() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        this.entityManager.clear();
    }

    @Transactional
    public Role Role.merge() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        Role merged = this.entityManager.merge(this);
        this.entityManager.flush();
        return merged;
    }

}
```

I tried both MySql and Hsqldb database with the same code. But no luck.

I also have another problem. In case of development I didn't have to specify Role and User classes in persistence.xml. If I don't specify them in test configuration I'm getting exceptions.

Comment: Why are you not using your EntityManager in your test? Can you show your service layer logic where you say it works.

Comment: I'm using EntityManager which is available in Role class that is generated by Roo. I have attached that. With the exact same code in the test() function I'm able to save the entity Role from a controller, but cannot do it in this test case.

Answer (score 0):

Roo lets you to configure the persistence engine as many times as you need, try to reconfigure your persistence settings from Roo shell using `persistence setup` command

Comment: I do not have any problem persisting the Role entity in a controller. The problem is when I try the same inside a test case, the test passes but the entity is not persisted. (No Exceptions also.)

Comment: I think more info about your tests is needed, anyway try with "clinic.roo" and MySQL and check the results

Answer (score 0):

In your `applicationContext.xml` you specified the `context:component-scan base-package` to `com.campus` but your entities are on `com.company.domain`.

Have you changed the main package after the `web mvc` command?

Try to set `applicationContext.xml` like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*"
        type="regex" />
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
        type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Afther that, I think you can remove the `class` tags from `persistencie.xml`.

Comment: Sorry that's a typo. I have actually set it to "com.company". I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need the flush in there.  The insert statement doesn't get executed until flush is called.
And the findRolesByRolenameEquals method cannot read the object you have saved from the hibernate session as it uses a query to load the object

If you comment out the assert, and let the test finish, you should be able to see the record in the db as flush should occur when the transaction is complete, is that not the case?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by removing component-scan from my applicationContext.xml. Now I'm able to persist data into the database(both MySql and Hsqldb) from the test case. Now the test case is passing and the data is seen in the database.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*"
        type="regex" />
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
        type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>
```

I still could not make out why this solved my problem. I am still finding a valid explanation here.

My other problem is still there. I had to manually put Role and User classes in persistence.xml.